# Update table set column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005, I have two tables:

`A (ID, PRODUCT)`
 `B(ID_2, PRODUCT)`

Now I want to `update table A.ID` and `Set A.ID=B.ID_2 where A.Product =B.Product`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an `INNER JOIN`

```
UPDATE A
SET A.ID = B.ID_2
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.Product = A.Product
```